# Identifying an app's users without having registered accounts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating a survey app that tracks a user's answered surveys, and later with the data be able to study the user's response. But I have a issue regarding this app, which is that it cannot have any kind of registration, and the only way I can track the users is by two types of identification that can be included in the form survey: "phone_number" and "email".

Since I can't create any kind of registration for the users it's not easy to track a unique user's answers, history, etc. The only way of identification is if the survey that the user is answering has an input of phone or email.
Can someone tell me what is the best approach in terms of creating this type of control of the data?

Comment: Can you just make sure you ask for email on every survey and use that to federate the data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make sure you ask for the email address on every survey and use that to federate the data?

Otherwise you can set a cookie which would allow tracking a session as long as the cookie exists.  Maybe store the email address and associate it with the session...  Then on save of a survey, check for a session, and if it exists you could append that email to the rest of the survey data you are about to store.  That gets around having to ask every time...

I'd envision an email field on every survey, pre populate with known email if you can, otherwise have them enter it.

Basically though the way web apps work is with cookies/sessions.